# Finding the correct elements for scraping a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape only certain articles from [this](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/) main page. To be more specific, I am trying to scrape only articles from sub-page media and from sub-sub-pages [Press releases](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/html/index.en.html); [Governing Council decisions](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/govcdec/html/index.en.html); [Press conferences](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/html/index.en.html); [Monetary policy accounts](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/accounts/html/index.en.html); [Speeches](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/key/html/index.en.html); [Interviews](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/html/index.en.html), and also just those which are in English.

I managed (based on some tutorials and other SE:overflow answers), to put together a code that scrapes completely everything from the website because my original idea was to scrape everything and then in data frame just clear the output later but the website includes so much that it always freezes after some time.

Getting the sub-links:

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
master_request = requests.get("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/")
base_url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu"
master_soup = BeautifulSoup(master_request.content, 'html.parser')
master_atags = master_soup.find_all("a", href=True)
master_links = [ ] 
sub_links = {}
for master_atag in master_atags:
    master_href = master_atag.get('href')
    master_href = base_url + master_href
    print(master_href)
    master_links.append(master_href)
    sub_request = requests.get(master_href)
    sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_request.content, 'html.parser')
    sub_atags = sub_soup.find_all("a", href=True)
    sub_links[master_href] = []
    for sub_atag in sub_atags:
        sub_href = sub_atag.get('href')
        sub_links[master_href].append(sub_href)
        print("\t"+sub_href)
```

Some things I tried were to change the base link to sublinks - my idea was that maybe I can just do it separately for every sub-page and later just put the links together but that did not work). Other things that I tried was to replace the 17th line with the following;

```
sub_atags = sub_soup.find_all("a",{'class': ['doc-title']}, herf=True)
```

this seemed to partially solve my problem because even though it did not got only links from the sub-pages it at least ignored links that are not 'doc-title' which are all the links with text on the website but it was still too much and some links were not retrieved correctly.

I tried also tried the following:

```py
for master_atag in master_atags:
    master_href = master_atag.get('href')
    for href in master_href:
        master_href = [base_url + master_href if str(master_href).find(".en") in master_herf
    print(master_href)
```

I thought that because all hrefs with English documents had .en somewhere in them this would only give me all links where .en occurs somewhere in the href but this code gives me syntax error for the print(master_href) which I dont understand because previously print(master_href) worked.

Next I want to extract the following information from sublinks. This part of code works when I test it for a single link, but I never had chance to try it on the above code since it wont finish running. Will this work once I manage to get the proper list of all links?

```
for links in sublinks:
    resp = requests.get(sublinks)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html5lib')
    article = soup.find('article')
    title = soup.find('title')
    textdate = soup.find('h2')
    paragraphs = article.find_all('p')
    matches = re.findall('(\d{2}[\/ ](\d{2}|January|Jan|February|Feb|March|Mar|April|Apr|May|May|June|Jun|July|Jul|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec)[\/ ]\d{2,4})', str(textdate))
        for match in matches:
        print(match[0])
        datadate = match[0]
import pandas as pd
ecbdf = pd.DataFrame({"Article": [Article]; "Title": [title]: "Text": [paragraphs], "date": datadate})
```

Also going back to the scraping, since the first approach with beautiful soup did not worked for me I also tried to just approach the problem differently. The website has RSS feeds so I wanted to use the following code:

```py
import feedparser
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
import requests
rss_url='https://www.ecb.europa.eu/home/html/rss.en.html'
ecb_feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url) 
df_ecb_feed=json_normalize(ecb_feed.entries)
df_ecb_fead.head()
```

Here I run into a problem of not being even able to find the RSS feed url in the first place. I tried the following: I viewed the source page and I tried to search for "RSS" and tried all urls that I could find this way but I always get empty dataframe.

I am a beginner to web-scraping and at this point I dont know how to proceed or how to approach this problem. In the end what I want to accomplish is to just collect all articles from the subpages with their titles, and dates and authors and put them into one dataframe.

Comment: i just try to understand, what you want to scrape from the links ? it's not clear for me yet, for example for that [url](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/html/index.en.html) what you want to extract?

Comment: For example, from this https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/date/2019/html/ecb.pr191220~beda4133de.en.html

Comment: what do you want to get from that link exactly ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I would like to turn it into a row in data frame with columns like this: pd.DataFrame({"Article": [Article]; "Title": [title]: "Text": [paragraphs], "date": datadate}). So basically the whole raw article, then separate article title and separate text and separate date also if there is an author then also that (although most of them dont have one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem you have with scraping this site is probably the lazy loading: Using JavaScript, they load the articles from several html pages and merge them into the list. For details, look out for `index_include` in the source code. This is problematic for scraping with only requests and BeautifulSoup because what your soup instance gets from the request content is just the basic skeleton without the list of articles. Now you have two options:

1. Instead of the main article list page (Press Releases, Interviews, etc.), use the lazy-loaded lists of articles, e.g., `/press/pr/date/2019/html/index_include.en.html`. This will probably be the easier option, but you have to do it for each year you're interested in.
2. Use a client that can execute JavaScript like Selenium to obtain the HTML instead of requests.

Apart from that, I would suggest to use CSS selectors for extracting information from the HTML code. This way, you only need a few lines for the article thing. Also, I don't think you have to filter for English articles if you use the `index.en.html` page for scraping because it shows English by default and -- additionally -- other languages if available.

Here's an example I quickly put together, this can certainly be optimized but it shows how to load the page with Selenium and extract the article URLs and article contents:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

base_url = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu'
urls = [
    f'{base_url}/press/pr/html/index.en.html',
    f'{base_url}/press/govcdec/html/index.en.html'
]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    for anchor in soup.select('span.doc-title > a[href]'):
        driver.get(f'{base_url}{anchor["href"]}')
        article_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

        title = article_soup.select_one('h1.ecb-pressContentTitle').text
        date = article_soup.select_one('p.ecb-publicationDate').text
        paragraphs = article_soup.select('div.ecb-pressContent > article > p:not([class])')
        content = '\n\n'.join(p.text for p in paragraphs)

        print(f'title: {title}')
        print(f'date: {date}')
        print(f'content: {content[0:80]}...')
```

I get the following output for the Press Releases page:

```
title: ECB appoints Petra Senkovic as Director General Secretariat and Pedro Gustavo Teixeira as Director General Secretariat to the Supervisory Board                         
date: 20 December 2019                                    
content: The European Central Bank (ECB) today announced the appointments of Petra Senkov...

title: Monetary policy decisions                          
date: 12 December 2019                                    
content: At today’s meeting the Governing Council of the European Central Bank (ECB) deci...
```

Comment: Totally forgot one thing in my answer: Since you know which pages you want to scrape I would also suggest iterating over a list of start URLs (`urls` in my example) instead of scraping the whole site and filtering out stuff you don't want to extract.