# How to scrape the correct elements from the ECB website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the press statements and speeches from the website below.

My problem is very similar to this question. [Finding the correct elements for scraping a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773096/finding-the-correct-elements-for-scraping-a-website)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

base_url = 'https://www.ecb.europa.eu'
urls = [
    f'{base_url}/press/pr/html/index.en.html',
    f'{base_url}/press/govcdec/html/index.en.html'
]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    for anchor in soup.select('span.doc-title > a[href]'):
        driver.get(f'{base_url}{anchor["href"]}')
        article_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

        title = article_soup.select_one('h1.ecb-pressContentTitle').text
        date = article_soup.select_one('p.ecb-publicationDate').text
        paragraphs = article_soup.select('div.ecb-pressContent > article > p:not([class])')
        content = '\n\n'.join(p.text for p in paragraphs)

        print(f'title: {title}')
        print(f'date: {date}')
        print(f'content: {content[0:80]}...')
```

However, I´ve tried to run it and do not get any output. I have very little experience in HTML. In particular, I do not understand what this is part is looping over. Something related to CSS.

```
for anchor in soup.select('span.doc-title > a[href]'):
```

So my suspicion is that its not working anymore as there was recently a change in the layout of ECB's webpage. I guess the html reference were change, but I don't know exactly

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

may I know what answer you exactly need? You can use .find_all() to find all elements of a particular tag, class, or id.
Tag: Type the name of the tag in a string
Class: Type class_="TheNameOfClass"
Id: Type id="NameOFID"

Hope this helped. Do make sure to ask anything else if you have a doubt on it.

Comment: I need the following

<div class="title"> <h1>Unconventional fiscal and monetary (...) </h1>
<h2 class="ecb-pressContentSubtitle">Keynote speech by Isabel Schnabel, (...)”</h2>
<p class="ecb-publicationDate">Frankfurt am Main, 26 February 2021</p>
<p>One of the greatest conundrums (...) 
So my output would look like

title: Unconventional fiscal and monetary policy (...) subtitle: Keynote speech by Isabel Schnabel, (...)
date: 20 December 2019
content: One of the greatest conundrums (...)

Answer (score 0):

I need the following

```
<div class="title"> <h1>Unconventional fiscal and monetary (...) </h1>
<h2 class="ecb-pressContentSubtitle">Keynote speech by Isabel Schnabel, (...)”</h2>
<p class="ecb-publicationDate">Frankfurt am Main, 26 February 2021</p>
<p>One of the greatest conundrums (...)
```

So my output would look like

title: Unconventional fiscal and monetary policy (...)
subtitle: Keynote speech by Isabel Schnabel, (...)
date: 20 December 2019
content: One of the greatest conundrums (...)

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay, so firstly you will get an error in `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`. Inside the parenthesis you should paste the exact path to the webdriver installed. If you do not have a webdriver for chrome follow the instructions given below. Now if you have the webdriver path specified there and do not want to leak it to others, Ok its fine.

Next, Instead of using beautiful soup you can use selenium itself for scraping elements. Use `driver.find_element_by_class_name("")` and type in the class name you want to search by. For this case it will be "title". Next you want to get the text of the h1. I dont exactly know how to find children in selenium you can search that up and use the command to get the code of h1. Store it in a variable and you can print the text of it like this `print(h1.text)`. Note: Search up how to get children elements of a tag from selenium then use the command mentioned in any website and then use .text

Instructions:

1. Check your chrome version
2. Go to this website https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
3. Click on the link which matches with your chrome version.
4. Download the version that fits your pc.
5. Unzip the file and get the path and paste it in `webdriver.Chrome()`.

Thats all. If my answer didnt satisfy you please make sure to ask cuz im not that of an expert at selenium. I too am an apprentice.

Answer (score 0):

I had webdriver already installed so that was not the problem. Now I have basically just removed the second loop and corrected the elements and it works :)

```
date = article_soup.select_one('p.ecb-publicationDate').text 
title = article_soup.select_one('title').text 
subtitle = article_soup.select_one('h2.ecb-pressContentSubtitle').text
paragraphs = article_soup.select('div.section > p:not([class])')
content = '\n\n'.join(p.text for p in paragraphs)

#print(date)
#print(title)
#print(subtitle)
#print(content)
```